# Public API for all state tax names

Tags: api, tax

Is there any public API which returns the tax names for all the states across all countries ?

Comment: Do you mean sales tax rates API? What taxes exactly?

Comment: @G.Dimov : Yes, sales tax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some APIs.

About pricing, some are completely free, some are based on usage and others have free trial versions.

Taxjar: [github.com](https://github.com/taxjar)*, [developers.taxjar.com](https://developers.taxjar.com/api/reference/?javascript)

AvaTax: [developer.avalara.com](https://developer.avalara.com/api-reference/avatax/rest/v2/methods/Free/), [www.avalara.com](https://www.avalara.com/us/en/blog/2017/03/avatax-free-trial.html)

USGeocoder: [usgeocoder.com](https://usgeocoder.com/api_salestax)

FastTax: [www.serviceobjects.com](https://www.serviceobjects.com/products/ecommerce-fasttax/fasttax)

SalesTaxPAL: [www.salestaxpal.com](https://www.salestaxpal.com/docs/rest_api_user_guide.htm)

*GitHub link to the Taxjar profile since each language has its own repository.

Comment: Can you specify which api provides state tax name ? I could not find that in the above links. There is one but only for US and Canada.

Comment: Please, take a look at [gt4m.com](https://gt4m.com/), [taxrates.io](https://taxrates.io/) and [sovos.com](https://sovos.com/products/tax-determination/).